# maven dependencies.dependency.version missing of sibling

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

I have a parent project and 2 child projects - all of them present in a directory.

```
    Main Directory
    |__Parent
    |__Child 1
    |__Child 2
```

Child 2 is dependent on Child 1. Parent has dependency-management defined with all the common dependencies of Child 1 and 2.

All the 3 projects' version is same. In child 2 pom's dependencies section, child 1 is listed without version and I'm getting dependencies.dependency.version missing error.

Is there any work around without adding child 1 to parent pom's dependency management section or explicitly having child 1's version in child 2's pom?

Comment: In all multimodule maven projects I've worked with the child projects' versions have been declared in dependency management section, since they'd be dependencies to each other just like projects/libraries outside of the main project.

Comment: Why you don't want to add child1 to parent dependencies?